# how to trigger function upon azure active directory changes

Tags: azure

I am creating an application and trying to understand as, how to trigger an azure function when a new user or role  is added to azure active directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - this isn't going to be an exact 'how to' answer, sorry, but this is something similar to what I've been looking for recently as well.

What I have found thus far (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) is that there does not appear to be a direct way to trigger or bind to Azure Active Directory from Azure Functions. However, in that link it does list Event Hubs as a option.

That led me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub which gives a sample of how to stream Azure Active Directory logs to an Event Hub.

If you put the two together, it does seem possible, and I will be starting something similar myself in the next few weeks, so I would be interested in how this turns out for you.

Good luck!

Comment: had a suspicion i could do something with event hub :), but great to confirm.. I will most likely take that approach. To your knowledge, logic apps could be helpful?

Comment: sorry - I haven't used logic apps, so I can't comment on them